# Need to hide ONLY specific '.answer' when the quest. to that answer is clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now this function hides all shown answers. I need it to only hide the answer that belongs to a particular question that is clicked a second time. I am very new to JQuery so there is probably a simple solution to this, but any help would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".question").click(function () {
            $('.answer').hide(); // hides open answers before showing a new answer 
        if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) { // check the visibility of the next element in the DOM
            $(this).next().show(); // show it
        } else {
            $(this).next().hide(); // hide it
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the html too. That would help!

Comment: put html also  here or create jsfiddle

Comment: so you need counter for each question!. and you have  to store that as a flag to check  question  is clicked . if counter>1 hide ....something like this  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-a-button-disabled-after-3-clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no HTML to go off of, I've mocked up an example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gjRY/1/):

**HTML**

```
<span class="question">What is your name?</span>
<span class="answer">Chase</span>
<br/>
<label class="question">How old are you?</label>
<span class="answer">25</span>
<br/>
<label class="question">What is your favorite color?</label>
<span class="answer">Blue</span>
<br/>
<label class="question">Do you like cheese?</label>
<span class="answer">Duh</span>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".question").click(function () {
     $(this).next("span.answer").fadeToggle();
   });
});
```

I'm using the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get the following `.answer` of the `click`ed `question`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you wouldn't mind, go ahead and mark it as the answer =)